# import android.view.View; cannot resolve symbol 'view'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-intent

In android studio 3.4.1 onClick listener, not fount   and now it showing setOnEditorActionListener

```
bth.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

import android.view.View;
    cannot resolve symbol 'view'

This was a working project, it is showing this error 
if I run it will run without any issue 
I open it from another `PC` and there is no issue like this.

I am using latest android studio 3.4.1

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    //firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.6'
    //slider
    implementation project(':library')
    //glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
    //recyclerview gravity
    implementation 'com.github.rubensousa:gravitysnaphelper:1.5'
    // rating library
    implementation 'com.github.ome450901:SimpleRatingBar:1.4.2'
    //cardview
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'

    //retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'

    //timber-logging interceptor
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.1'

    //round corner image
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'

    //Html tag remover
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'

    //    dots indicator
    implementation 'com.ryanjeffreybrooks:indefinitepagerindicator:1.0.10'
    implementation 'com.tbuonomo.andrui:viewpagerdotsindicator:2.1.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.7.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    // for unit test
    testImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.12.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.7.22'

    implementation 'com.github.sharish:ShimmerRecyclerView:v1.3'


}
```

I tried invalied cash and restart
restart pc
reinstall android studio
  But no result
My team member android studio confi
Android Studio 3.2.1
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 9, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

My android studio

Android Studio 3.4.1 
Build #AI-183.6156.11.34.5522156, built on May 2, 2019 
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01 amd64 
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o 
Windows 10 10.0

> The project is from git

Comment: Are you sure there's no other Gradle error? This kind of import failure is usually associated with a project that cannot sync/build to begin with. If you cannot import View, I bet there's a deeper issue in the project/gradle structure. I know you're saying if you run this, it works, does it work if you go to the command line and type `./gradlew clean assembleDebug` ? (in the project's folder)

Comment: but same code work in my team member pc

Comment: they are using old v of android studio and i am using latest

Comment: this is only the dreference

Comment: You're going to have to provide more information to be honest. You're essentially giving no information about what is different in your machine (other than the AS version). What version of Android Studio are your co-workers using?

Comment: please check i updated in question

Comment: Is your project on git? If yes then is all your code is committed? If yes then try deleting every non-git file(I assume your .gitignore file is correct) with `git clean -fxd`

Comment: After that import your project in Android Studio. Note: Do not open it directly but instead use import option. Please let me know the result.

Comment: If it didn't help then type `gradlew assembleDebug` in Android terminal and share the result.

Comment: Do this. In your co-worker's machine, checkout the project fresh from "git", like ` git clone <your project>` and try running it from Android Studio (The new copy, not the one that works). I think your project is incorrectly checked out in VCS and it just works on the original machine (I'm making this an assumption because -like I said- you're not telling us the whole picture, so we have to guess which pieces are what).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry this is coming late, I experienced the same problem and after hours of searching I discovered that the View class has been corrupted, you can fix the problem by deleting the platform in the SDK(android 28) and installing a new one, hope this helps Goodluck

Comment: +1, chkdsk had corrupted few times sdk files on my device, when i was on Windows.
but also could be a Gradle cache issue

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the following code in MainActivity.java

```
import android.view.View;
```